# How to view a tensorboard locally from a remote server using MobaXterm?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, tensorboard

My institution does not allow traditional ssh access. Is there a method for viewing a tensorboard locally from a remote server that uses SLURM scripting?

Comment: Can you take a look at this [link1](https://dlhr.de/12) and [link2](https://gist.github.com/taylorpaul/250ee3ed2524e8c28ee7c58ed656a5b9) which explains about `Tensorboard on SLURM` and let us know if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: This does not help as I cannot ssh into the cluster to access the local server.